# i am not able to reflect error message using service

Tags: angular

I am trying to display error message from backend using dynamic component.
i am passing the error from interceptor to errorservice.ts file.
From there i am passing it to error component.
but when application is running the message is not passed from errorservice to errorcomponent.
so the
i am expecting "AUTH FAILED" error message under An Error Occurred! but it is missing.

error.interceptor.ts

```
import {
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpErrorResponse
} from "@angular/common/http";
import { catchError } from "rxjs/operators";
import { throwError } from "rxjs";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { MatDialog } from "@angular/material";
import { ErrorComponent } from "./error/error.component";
import { ErrorService } from "./error/error.service";
 
@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
 
  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog,private errorService: ErrorService) {}
 
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        let errorMessage = "An unknown error occurred!";
        if (error.error.message) {
          errorMessage = error.error.message;
        }
        this.errorService.addMessage(errorMessage);
        this.dialog.open(ErrorComponent);   
        return throwError(error);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

error.service.ts

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core"; 
@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class ErrorService {

   errorListener = new Subject<string>(); 
  getErrorListener() {
    return this.errorListener.asObservable();
  }
  
  addMessage(message: string) {
    this.errorListener.next(message); 
  }
 
  handleError() {
    this.errorListener.next(null);
  }
  
}
```

error.component.ts

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from "@angular/material";
import { Subscription } from "rxjs";
 
import { ErrorService } from "./error.service";
 
@Component({
  templateUrl: "./error.component.html",
  selector: "app-error",
  styleUrls: ["./error.component.css"]
})
export class ErrorComponent implements OnInit {
  message:string; 
  private errorSub: Subscription;
 
 constructor(private errorService: ErrorService) {
 
 }
 
  ngOnInit() {
  this.errorSub = this.errorService.getErrorListener().subscribe(message => {
 this.message=message;
  });
  }
 
  onHandleError() {
    this.errorService.handleError();
  }
 
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.errorSub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

error.component.html

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>An Error Occurred!</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <p class="mat-body-1">{{ message }}</p>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Okay</button>
</div>
```

[image: Auth failed is not displaying under An error occurred!]

I appreciate any help in this issue.

Comment: Change errorListener to a behaviorSubject.

Comment: @MikeOne. Thanks it worked. May I know how it worked with Behavioural subject

Comment: Subject will only push to existing subscriptions, wheras BehaviourSubject will replay the last item to late subscribers - this being your case here. https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/subject

Comment: Yes, as plabbee mentioned. Bascially the emit on the Subject has already happened before you open the dialog. So you missed it. A behaviorSubject always emits the last value to new (late) subscribers.